# multivariable convex function

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus, convex-analysis

Consider the following two-variable function:
\begin{equation}
f(x,t)=h(x)+g(t)
\end{equation}
assume the following relation holds for $0\leq\lambda\leq 0$:
\begin{align}
&h(\lambda x +(1-\lambda) y)\leq \lambda h(x)+(1-\lambda)h(y)\notag\\
&g(\lambda t +(1-\lambda) s)\leq \lambda g(t)+(1-\lambda)g(s)
\end{align}
can we conclude that the function $f(x,t)$ is also convex?

more generally if we have an arbitrary two-variable function $k(x,t)$ which is convex w.r.t its individual arguments, can we conclude that it is convex as a multivariable function as well? i.e.

if
\begin{align}
&k\Big((\lambda x +(1-\lambda) y),t\Big)\leq \lambda k(x,t)+(1-\lambda)k(y,t)\notag\\
&k\Big(x,(\lambda t +(1-\lambda) s)\Big)\leq \lambda k(x,t)+(1-\lambda)k(x,s)
\end{align}
Can we conclude that
\begin{align}
&k\Big((\lambda x +(1-\lambda) y),(\lambda t +(1-\lambda) s)\Big)\leq \lambda k(x,t)+(1-\lambda)k(y,s)
\end{align}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to the first question is “yes”: Both functions
$$
 (x, t) \mapsto h(x) \\
 (x, t) \mapsto g(t)
$$
are convex, and the sum of convex functions is convex.

The answer to the second question is “no”: A counterexample is $f(x, t) = xt$, which is linear (and therefore convex) in both variables separately, but not convex:
$$
 1 = f(1, 1) \le \frac 12 \left( f(2, 0) + f(0, 2) \right) = 0
$$
does not hold.

Comment: Thank you, Is there a theorem or sth that states under what condition the answer to the second question would be "yes"?

Comment: @Jason: A twice differentiable function is convex if the Hession matrix is positive semi-definite. Convexity in each variable separately only ensures that the diagonal entries of the Hession are non-negative.

Comment: I meant "Hessian"